# Run jQuery plugin diff2html inside an Angular directive with noconflict

Tags: jquery, angularjs, diff2html

I'm trying to format a diff inside an Angular directive using [diff2html](https://github.com/rtfpessoa/diff2html) and `var jq = $.noConflict();`

I've created an Angular constant to hold jQuery and am passing it into the directive as so:

**app.js**

```
(function () { //IIFE to enable strict mode
    'use strict';

    angular.module('dashboard', ['ui.router', 'ngSanitize'])
        .config(['$interpolateProvider', function ($interpolateProvider) {
            $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[[').endSymbol(']]]');
        }])
        .constant('jQuery', window.jQuery);
})();
```

**directive.js**

```
(function () { //IIFE to enable strict mode

    'use strict';

    angular.module('dashboard')
        .directive("loadDiff", ['$http', 'jQuery', function($http, $) {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

                    $http.get("diff url here").success(function (data) {
                        var diff2htmlUi = new Diff2HtmlUI({diff: data});
                        diff2htmlUi.draw('#line-by-line');
                    });
                }
            }
        }]);
})();
```

**The Problem**

When it runs, I get the following error:

`TypeError: $ is not a function at Diff2HtmlUI._initSelection at new Diff2HtmlUI`

Debugging this you can see that when `Diff2HtmlUI` is instantiated it tries to set the body and this likely fails due to the conflict with `var jq = $.noConflict();`.

```
  Diff2HtmlUI.prototype._initSelection = function() {
    var body = $('body');
    var that = this;
```

How can I fix this issue? I was hoping passing in jQuery as `$` would override the noconflict conflict?

Comment: add jquery before angular, remove this constant cause it is useless. Defininf function($http, $) is funny but not doing anything...

Comment: @PetrAveryanov jQuery is already defined as the first include. That answer was suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34402898/pass-jquery-dependency-to-angular-js-controller

Comment: See this demo, I cannot reproduce the bug: http://plnkr.co/edit/hLnuvQ9kHRRdsaHYK3SS?p=preview

Comment: Question edited, issue is related to `var jq = $.noConflict();`

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get why you are passing `jQuery` down to your directive. Since you loaded it directly, you and `diff2html` already have access to it through the global `window` object.

Also, you probably just want to pass the directive `element` instead of an external div id, just pass it as `$(elem)` since it expects a jQuery object or DOM query string.

```js
angular.module('dashboard', [])
  .config(['$interpolateProvider', function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[[').endSymbol(']]]');
  }])
  .constant('jQuery', window.jQuery)
  .directive('loadDiff', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

        $http({
          url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/rtfpessoa/diff2html/pulls/106.diff',
          headers: {
            accept: 'application/vnd.github.v3.diff'
          }
        })
        .then(function (resp) {
          var diff2htmlUi = new Diff2HtmlUI({ diff: resp.data });
          diff2htmlUi.draw($(elem));
        })
          
      }
    }
  }]);
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/diff2html/2.3.0/diff2html.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/diff2html/2.3.0/diff2html.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/diff2html/2.3.0/diff2html-ui.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="dashboard">
    <div load-diff="load-diff">Loading diff...</div>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Question updated, related to `var jq = $.noConflict();` and Angular running after this.

Comment: With `$` still injected in the directive? can you try removing it?