# How to use "$" in an ionic angularJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my ionic angularJS app, I'm trying to add a loading page with a moving text inside. I found a CSS template with in it a JS code.

My problem is the use of `"$"` (which is the node I guess, isn't it ?), I tried to add `"$"` as dependency in my controller but I'm getting an `unknown provider` error.

Because IONIC is an angularJS template and angularJS is pure JS, I suppose that is it possible to use this function, but how to do it ?

```js
// MY CONTROLLER ** NOT WORKING ** 
.controller('loadingCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$', function ($scope, $stateParams, $) {

// Wrap every letter in a span
$('.ml9 .letters').each(function(){
  $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/([^\x00-\x80]|\w)/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"));
});

anime.timeline({loop: true})
  .add({
    targets: '.ml9 .letter',
    scale: [0, 1],
    duration: 1500,
    elasticity: 600,
    delay: function(el, i) {
      return 45 * (i+1)
    }
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml9',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 1000
  });

}])
```

```css
.ml9 {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 4em;
}

.ml9 .text-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.2em;
  padding-right: 0.05em;
  padding-bottom: 0.1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ml9 .letter {
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ion-view title="Loading" style="background-color:#94D0F1;">
  <ion-content padding="true">
    <h1 class="ml9">
      <span class="text-wrapper">
        <span class="letters">Loading ...</span>
      </span>
    </h1>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: The `$` is jQuery. You won't be able to inject it as a provider in your application but instead it will be available globally as `$`

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the following command npm install --save-dev @types/jquery 
, and import it in you module

Answer (score 0):

`$` is a constant defined by `jQuery` on the `window` which is why it is often globally accessible in a web app. You do not have to inject it as there are frequently alternatives to working directly with jQuery in angularjs. I recommend you do not write ui specific code in your controllers, use a directive instead as the intent of a controller should be to house business logic and directives can be used to manipulate the DOM.

That said: The error occurs because you are trying to inject it using the named injector `$` which angularjs does not know about. You can register it though and then inject it as you see fit. Add the following line after you create your application. Also be sure to register the `jquery` script in the HTML *before* your angular script so `window.jQuery` exists.

```
app.constant('$', window.jQuery)
```

---

See also

- [Pass jQuery dependency to angular js controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34402898)
- [How to use jQuery in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666289)